# Bootstrap Grid system doesn't work in modal dialog

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

In a modal dialog I have defined a form like continue:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <label for="name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 text-left">
                    <span class="invalid-icon" title="Error!"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The icon in the last column is outside the modal dialog. See screenshot. Any idea?

[image]

If I define only 11 columns and I add the span next to the input text in the ninth column, it works. Why doesn't work if I define 12 columns?

Comment: set dark layer behind ng-modal

Comment: Both `.form-group` and `.row` give 15px negative margin, try remove the `div.row`.

Comment: @SandeepC.Nath It does if its child of `.form-horizontal`. `.form-horizontal .form-group {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}`

Comment: I'm going to try that. I think I have some style that avoids to get the expected result

Comment: @tmg I apologize for my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try with label in div with col-md-2

```
<div class="col-md-2">
<label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
</div>
```

also make error div invisible instead of display none form-horizontal also needed to be looked at